# Pattern matching with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am a novice in regex and trying to understand it by solving small problems. So here I am with a problem which I couldn't solve (warning: it may be extremely silly). Your inputs will help me understand the concept.

I want to write a regex which will match all items in `list1` but none of those from `list2`

**list1**

```
   pit
   spot
   spate
   slap two
   respite
```

**list2**

```
   pt
   Pot
   peat
   part
```

I was thinking like "give me all the items that starts with `p|s|r` and endswith `it|ot|e|o`
So i wrote `^[p|s|r].*[it|ot|e|o]$` which eventually resulted in undesired result.

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Not all regex's are equal... you may want to say whether this is Java, Perl, or whatever.

Comment: The reason your regex isn't working is because you put the conditions inside *character classes* `[]` rather than in *subpattern groupings* `()`. I don't think you've got the best answer there, but `^(p|s|r).*?(it|ot|e|o)$` should work.

Comment: We have an app for that... ehm I meant a tag :-)

Comment: @xanatos: Thanks for pointing that out.. That didn't struck my head while posting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In notepad you can't do `or` operations (taken from [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html) and tested on my Notepad++ 5.9.3)

This would work in other "standard" regexes :-)

```
^[psr].*(it|ot|e|o)$
```

Try here. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uudn

What were you doing was using the `[]` instead of the grouping `()`. It was equivalent to: `[itoe|]` (were the `|` was a "standard" character instead of `or`) and in general everything in an `[]` is in or :-) `[ab]` means `a` or `b`.

Comment: You have the same error in the first character class. It is somewhat less problematic from a practical point of view, but probably harms understanding.

Comment: @tripleee I was checking what n++ can do in regexes and I noticed it :-) In the end it can't be done in n++ as asked by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(pit|spot|spate|slap two|respite)/.test('Pot')
```

This matches the words from list one, and none from list two

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I must be missing something.

```
^(pit|spot|spate|slap two|respite)$
```

Comment: lol, funny answer, but doesn't really help with learning regex beyond whole word matching

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how you categorise the differences between the lists:

```
/p[ioa\s]t/
```